# how do I make the esri geometry and map functions available for execution in python using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, arcgis-js-api

I want to draw polygon on arcgis map through selenium. I understand that I need to get the real world x,y converted to screen x,y and use that to draw points on the map. I found the following python code online which executes JS but it looks like `esri.geometry` and `map` objects have to be available in the global scope for the JS to execute. Is there a way to load the esri geometry and map js api within my python code?

```py
def realUnits2ScreenUnits(driver, x, y, wkid, refEle):

  #Pass JavaScript to the client browser to get screen units based on its real world location

  jscode = '''
    var realPoint = esri.geometry.Point({"x":%f, "y":%f, "spatialReference":{"wkid":%d}});
    sp = map.toScreen(realPoint); return ({'x': sp.x, 'y':sp.y}); ''' % (x, y, wkid)

  screenXY = driver.execute_script(jscode)  

  return screenXY
```

Comment: So you want to use selenium to interact with an arcgis js API web map? What is your goal here?

If you want to add a polygon i'm assuming that means editing a feature service, it would be easier to just doing that using Python through the ArcGIS REST API.

Comment: @BigGerman the goal is to test an inhouse developed application functionality which should return some data that exists within the polygon. I need selenium to draw the polygon and assert the data that is returned by the application backend service. I am using selenium cause thats what I am using for functional testing other parts of the application(which are non arcgis related)

Comment: Ah, okay for functional testing that is understandable. The thing about trying to execute the js code on the page is that all code for the the ArcGIS JS API is usually written within a function (in order to make use of Dojo AMD for module loading) and is thus not available in the global namespace. Do you need to draw the polygon in a specific location or can it be anywhere (geographically)? If the polygon doesn't need to be drawn with any particular geometry then you could just do it by initiating click events. This would allow you to test input and test that some sort of output is received

Comment: For verifying output for a particular input you are probably best sticking to unit testing for this, as you can do that easily through the rest api.

Comment: @BigGerman can you point me to a sample code that unit tests something similar?

Comment: Well you can [add a feature](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/add-features.htm) and check the response. Then [query](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/query-feature-service-.htm) the feature. This is obviously just testing the server, not the front-end. For unit testing the front-end you will need to use a Javascript test framework. [Here is one resource on that](https://github.com/DavidSpriggs/intern-tutorial-esri-jsapi)